# How to add conditional compilation in resx file in xml format?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, embedded-resource, conditional-compilation

NET project in which I need to add contents in the resource file (which is an xml file) based on certain compilation symbols.

something like the following:

```
<xml ....>
<myNodes>

#if SOMECONDITION
<node1>
...
</node1>

#else
<node2>
...
</node2>

#endif
</myNodes>
```

Is this even possible to do? I know this doesn't follow the XML rules. Is there similar method to use Conditional Compilation and yet to adhere to XML rules?

Answer (score 0):

I am no 100% sure that this resolves your issue but you can try condition constructs. there is no such a Conditional Compilation in xml.

```
 <rule>
    <if>
         <condition var="''$(Configuration)'" operator="=;">Debug</condition>
            <!-- more conditions possible -->
        </conditions>
        <statements>
            <!-- put your tage here -->
            <node1> ... </node1>
        </statements>
    </if>
    <else>
        <node2>
        ...
        </node2>
    </else>
</rule>
```